# Delphi iOS screen reader support for blind users

Tags: ios, delphi, screen-readers

I have an old iOS app developed in Delphi / FireMonkey. Now the customer calls and says he app does not work with screen readers - and if there is a solution for that.

i guess i will have to upgrade to the lates Delphi version, but beyond that - is it at all possible with Delphi / FireMonkey controls? I can see they have FireMonkey JAWS / VoiceOver support for screenreaders in OSX and Windows, but not iOS it seems?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is what happens when you don't use native UI.

Comment: Yes, but then again, FireMonkey supports it for OSX and Windows, so not unreasonable to hope for it for iOS as well :)

Comment: Quite unreasonable I'm afraid. As I said, since you are not using native UI, you will be lacking a great many features that are part of the UI. There are accessibility toolkits that can be added on to FMX.  Emba offer one. When you take the decision to use FMX you really ought to be aware of what you are leaving behind.

Comment: You call it unreasonable to hope for Embarcadero having an accessibility addon for FMX on iOS - yet agree that it indeed exists for two platforms already. It is fine if Delphi does not support support accessibility with FMX on iOS - in that case that is the answer I am looking for. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could I start over, I probably would. However, I am not totally hooked at XCode / ObjectiveC, but if my hand is forced I will probably make the switch. However, as of now, i have working code in FMX and Delphi XE7/XE8 seem to have improved the situaion drasticly compared to XE4/XE5, so I am tempted at delivering next versions in Delphi as well

Comment: There is no difference in the native model between VoiceOver support for a control in Mac OS X an that same control in iOS. If it works on Mac OS X and does not work on iOS then your tools have shut you out.

Comment: If anyone tries Delphi Seattle - feel free to report back or if your hear anything about it working - either out of the box or with some fiddling

Comment: I'm currently battling with accessibility on Windows using FMX. The docs say it supports TComboBox and TComboEdit, however it does not support them in the same way as TListBox, i.e. dropping the list down and using the up/down keys to select an item does not "read" the selected text. 

If you derive from (for example) TCustomEdit rather than TEdit, you either need to change the FMX screenreader source, or implement IFMXAccessibility in each of your controls. It could have been made a lot easier by having the screenreader based around the TCustomXXX controls rather than the concrete classes

Comment: A simple test app on OSX does not work at all (for me). VoiceOver claims that the active control is the close button (top left), despite setting focus to controls on the form. The struggle continues..